# f:param in p:ajax with p:selectonemenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF project using Java 8, JSF 2.2 and primefaces 5.3 running on Tomcat 8.
I have pages with parameters (http://server/app/page?x=1).
I have a form with `p:commandButton` updating some page parts with AJAX. When I submit the form the POST request is built correctly and contains also the page parameters (x = 1) passed with `f:param`.
I have however other form with `p:selectOneMenu` with an `p:ajax` and an AJAX listener changing some other form components. BUT the AJAX call does **NOT** include the page `f:param` parameters (x = 1) in this case into the POST message and thus the backing bean is unable to read proper data from DB and build requested page parts.

**The question is: how to pass the page parameters to the `p:ajax` call...?**

*I know there is an option to pass the parameters as arguments to the listener, but in this case the parameters are not visible to other beans and components used to build the page.
I'm using `@RequestScoped` beans and `@ManagedProperty` to set up the page parameters and it makes the code clean and simple. Using parameters for ALL XHTML calls would be a mess...*

Comment: Omnifaces `<o:form useRequestURI="true">` might be what you are looking for http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form

Comment: So to add another library? :-/ (to existing Primefaces and Bootsfaces)
Would this `o:form` resolve problem in the `p:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: This is an utility library that will save you tons of time, in my opinion, it shoud be used in almost every JSF projects... It makes your life easier for a lot of tasks (converter, resource and tag handlers, ..)

Comment: Replacing your surrounding `h:form` by `o:form` with  `includeRequestParams="true"` or `useRequestURI="true"` will keep and pass the page parameters.

Comment: Ok... so after many hours I've made it... in fact it was not only about adding a single library but it caused quite a LOT of other changes - mainly moving from Tomcat to Tomee, from ManagedBean/Properties to CDI...
Just post your hint as a full response so I can tick it as solved... and thanks of course!

Now I'm almost there... but all has caused a problem I can't overcome - reloading the app. in the development mode causes an excpetion when loading persisted sessions... I'll post another question as I can't find the same case here.